# Autoboxing: Why Short S1 = 100; compiled ok, but Long F1 = 100; failed?

Tags: java, autoboxing

I understand compiling `Long F1 = 100;` would fail, since 100 is an integer so compiler will box it to be `Integer`, and the wrapper types can not be widened.

But why would compiling `Short S1 = 100;` succeed? Thank you so much for helping.

Comment: Java. I am using JDK 1.7

Comment: In that case, can you tag your question with the relevant language next time? That way, people don't have to guess at the language, and you don't get answers touching on languages that you don't use.

Comment: i think that `Short` should be `short`

Comment: @SSpoke, the question here is related to Java's "Autoboxing" feature, where a primitive type (e.g. `short`) is converted by the compiler into its corresponding wrapper object (e.g. `Short`) to save the programmer from repetitive code (e.g. `Short myNum = Short.valueOf(10)`).

Answer (score 2):

From chapter 3 of [SCJP:](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0071591060)

> The following is legal,
>
> `byte b = 27;`
>
> but only because the compiler automatically narrows the literal value
>   to a byte.  In other words, the compiler puts in the cast.  The
>   preceding code is identical to the following:
>
> `byte b = (byte) 27; // Explicitly cast the int literal to a byte`
>
> It looks as though the compiler gives you a break, and lets you take a
>   shortcut with assignments to integer variables smaller than an int. 
>   (Everything we're saying about byte applies equally to char and short,
>   both of which are smaller than an int)

In your case the compiler is using:

```
Short s = (short)100;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you put suffix l/L to the literal that will compile 
like bellow Long F1 = 100l;  or
            Long F1 = 100L;